# Uninstalled module prevent upgrade

Tags: drush, 9, upgrading

I have been asked to upgrade a site from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9.

Previously, there was a very problematic module called 'support_ticket' that caused many issues and would not properly uninstall. After a lot of work - I thought - it had been removed.

However, when running the `drush updb` command after the drupal 9 upgrade I got the following error:

```
>  [notice] Update started: system_post_update_entity_revision_metadata_bc_cleanup
>  [error]  Drupal\support_ticket\SupportTicketStorage does not implement Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageInterface 
>  [error]  Update failed: system_post_update_entity_revision_metadata_bc_cleanup 
 [error]  Update aborted by: system_post_update_entity_revision_metadata_bc_cleanup 
 [error]  Finished performing updates.
```

The following steps have been previously taken to purge this module (After the normal uninstall did not work)

- Key-value entries removed from database
- entities updated and removed that referenced the module
- All tables associated with the module dropped from the DB (the ones we can find anyway)
- All files/directories associated with the module removed (I have grep'd the entire code base and I can find no reference to it).

Most of this was done months ago and I thought the module was completely gone until I tried to run the final update with Drupal 9.

How do I get rid of this thing so I can update drupal?

Comment: Are you certain there is not a file named SupportTicketStorage.php in the codebase?

Comment: No, but you gave me the idea of pulling a dump of the DB and greping for the module and I found some extra entries in the key_value table under a sub-modules name that had been missed, so now it's fixed. thanks so much!